# SQL function. Returning date + a few days

Tags: sql, oracle, function, sysdate

Im very new to SQL developer coding and i dont really know how all the code is suppose to be written and i need some help. 
I need to make an easy function to return a return date that is suppose to end up like this:

```
SQL> SELECT get_returndate(7)
     FROM dual;
_________
GET_RETURNDATE(7)
----------------------------
2013-10-21:23:59
___
```

It's suppose to take 1 parameter and then return `sysdate + parameter` as a date.

This is what i got

```
create or replace
  function get_retdate(
    p_days number)
  return date
  as
    v_retdate date;
    v_currdate date := sysdate;
  begin
    select v_date + p_days
    into v_retdate
    return
    from dual;
  end;
```

My problem is that i don't know how to add the parameter to the local variable in the function since im very new to SQL and functions, So i haven't gotten anywhere... I bet this is very easy and I'm just not good with SQL.

Comment: Since you're using Oracle you'd simply type: `SELECT SYSDATE + 7 FROM DUAL;`. You could wrap this in a function but I don't see why you'd bother.

Answer (score 0):

I hail to your beginner attempt at ***Oracle programming***, and you where close to it. But you must look into the manual.

Here is how you should have gone:

```
 create or replace function get_retdate( p_days number)
 return date
 as
   v_retdate date;
   v_currdate date := sysdate;
 begin
   select v_currdate + p_days into v_retdate from dual;
   return v_retdate;
 end get_retdate;
 /
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using MS SQL, use DATEADD: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp

Example:

```
DECLARE SevenDaysFromNow DATETIME = DATEADD(d,7,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score -1):

Transact-SQL (SQL Server) offers a very simple solution, no stored procedure is required:

```
SELECT GETDATE() + 7;
```

Gives in my timezone:

```
2013-10-24 00:29:54.137
```